# Remove from List<> duplicated items and record duplicated quantity

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a `List<Item>`. `Item` has properties `Id`,`Name` and `Amount`. There are duplicated items in this list. I need to get a new `List<Item>` which contains only non-duplicated `Item`s and in `Item`'s `Amount` should be the quantity of how many times it duplicated in first `List<Item>`. I tried something like

```
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
                {
                        if (list[i].Name == list[j].Name)
                        {
                            list.Remove(prod.Components[j]);
                            list[i].Amount++;
                        }
                }
            }
```

but there are some problems in this loop. My brains are overheated. Please, help.

Comment: what is duplicate in your context? just id or id and name?

Comment: how do you know `prod.Components[j]` exists? and you don't account for your moving index.

Comment: Because you are removing items in loop, `list.Count` and index of items changes while loop is going on and this causes exceptions (like `IndexOutOfRangeException`)

Comment: I would suggest class Item should implement IEquatable which makes the comparison easy, but you already got some nice linq solutions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple LINQ query can get you the unique items along with the number of times they appear:

```
var distinct = list.GroupBy(o => o.Name)
                   .Select(g => new { Count = g.Count(), Item = g.First() })
                   .ToList();
```

Then you can modify each item's `Amount` to the count of duplicates:

```
foreach (var row in distinct)
{
    row.Item.Amount = row.Count;
}
```

And finally get back a `List<Item>` that contains no duplicates and has the correct amounts:

```
var uniqueItems = distinct.Select(r => r.Item).ToList();
```

**Important:** The code above assumes that "duplicate" items are indistinguishable from each other, but nothing else (e.g. it doesn't need `Item` to have a default constructor). Depending on the particulars it may be possible to write it in an even shorter form.

Additionally, the `Amount` property looks strange here. Since duplicates do not warrant summation of their amounts, what's the purpose of `Item.Amount`? I would assume that duplicate items with amount of 2 should result in one item with an amount of 4, but your code does not do that (and mine follows that lead).

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head (haven't tested it):

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new Item {
                            Name = x.Key,
                            Amount = x.Count()
                          })
    .ToList();
```

You haven't specified what happens to the Ids, so I've left ignored them.

(Note this creates a new list, rather than modifying the original).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
var groups = from item in items
             group item by item.Property
             into grouped
             select grouped;

var distinct = from g in groups
               let item = g.First()
               let amount = g.Count()
               select new Item {Property = item.Property, Amount = amount};
```

After that `distinct` contains `IEnumerable<Item>` with their amount from original items list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you determine duplicates by the first two properties `ID` and `Name`.

You can implement an `IEqualityComparer<Item>` and use that for `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
var itemAmounts = items.GroupBy(i => i, new Item())
    .Select(g => new Item { 
        ID = g.First().ID, 
        Name = g.First().Name, 
        Amount = g.Count()
    });
```

Here's your Item class with a meaningful implementation of `IEqualityComparer<Item>`:

```
class Item : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int Amount;

    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;

        bool equals = x.ID == y.ID && x.Name == y.Name;
        return equals;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return int.MinValue;

        int hash = 19;
        hash = hash + obj.ID.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash + obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

You could also override `Equals` and `GetHasdhCode` from `object`, then you don't need a custom comparer at all in `GroupBy`:

```
var itemAmounts = items.GroupBy(i => i)
    .Select(g => new Item { 
        ID = g.First().ID, 
        Name = g.First().Name, 
        Amount = g.Count()
    });
```

You can use above already available methods:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Item item2 = obj as Item;
    if (item2 == null)
        return false;
    else
        return Equals(this, item2);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return GetHashCode(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    if(list.Count(e=>e.Id == item.Id && e.Name == item.Name)!=1)
    {
        list.Remove(item);
    }
}
```